# How to remove \r\n from string at :

Tags: javascript, node.js, split

Hey im trying to split a line read from a file, the file contains several lines that read like

```
username:password\r\n
username:password\r\n
username:password\r\n
```

And so on im not sure how to do them all at the same time and split them into 2 different vars one for username and one for password.

Comment: `.split(":")` ?

Comment: i tried that and also tried .toString so i could re-split at the \r\n and then it would just add a comma inplace of the :

Comment: What have you tried? Show your code.

Comment: Passwords stored as plaintext in a file?  Should I stop helping now as a matter of principle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a regex and [`matchAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll), and passing the returned iterator to [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and using the built in `map()` to return objects. (Has the added benefit of allowing `:` in passwords)

```js
const input = 'user1:password1\r\nuser2:password2\r\nuser3:password3\r\n';

const result = Array.from(
  input.matchAll(/(.+?):(.+?)\r\n/g),
  ([, username, password]) => ({ username, password })
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code.

```js
var mainStr = "username:password\r\nusername:password\r\nusername:password\r\n";

var usernameArr = [];
var passwordArr = [];
mainStr.split("\r\n").forEach(str => {
  var strArr = str.split(":");
  strArr[0] && usernameArr.push(strArr[0]);
  strArr[1] && passwordArr.push(strArr[1]);
});
console.log("Username ", usernameArr);
console.log("Password ", passwordArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

use .replace method

```
const str ='username:password\r\n'
const username = str.split(:)[0];
const password = str.split(:)[1].replace(/[\r\n]+/g, '');
```

For full string:

```
const str =`username:password\r\n
username:password\r\n
username:password\r\n`;

const res = str.split(/[\r\n]/g)
               .filter(l=>l!=="")
               .map(s=>({username:s.split(':')[0], password:s.split(':')[1]}));

console.log(res)
// [{username:'username', password:'password'},...];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert that into an array of key/value pairs

```js
let lines = `john:123443\r\n
alan:ffg1234\r\n
someone:xxghj!34\r\n`;

let pairs = lines.split("\r\n") // convert into an array
    .map(l => l.split(':') // split on the :
    .map(e => e.replaceAll("\r", "").replaceAll("\n", ""))) // clear out any extra newlines that lingered
    .filter(e => e.join('').trim() != '') // filter out any empties gathered along the way
    .map(grp => ({username: grp[0], password: grp[1]})) // transform the array into key/value pairs

console.log(pairs)
```